when i run pgadmin4 it gives this error: The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I get this error every time I run pgAdmin4:
Erorr:
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
Python Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3"
Runtime Config File: "/home/diyorbek/.config/pgadmin/runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/config.py"
Webapp Path: "/usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "/usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 -s /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py"
Environment:

HOME: /home/diyorbek
LANG: en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME: diyorbek
PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
SHELL: /bin/bash
USER: diyorbek
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: /run/user/1000
GTK_MODULES: gail:atk-bridge
QT_ACCESSIBILITY: 1
XDG_DATA_DIRS: /usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
DEBUGINFOD_URLS: https://debuginfod.ubuntu.com
DESKTOP_SESSION: ubuntu
DISPLAY: :1
GDMSESSION: ubuntu
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID: this-is-deprecated
GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE: ubuntu
GPG_AGENT_INFO: /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
GSM_SKIP_SSH_AGENT_WORKAROUND: true
PWD: /home/diyorbek
QT_IM_MODULE: ibus
SESSION_MANAGER: local/diyorbek-HP:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2664,unix/diyorbek-HP:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2664
SHLVL: 0
SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
USERNAME: diyorbek
WINDOWPATH: 2
XAUTHORITY: /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS: /etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: ubuntu:GNOME
XDG_MENU_PREFIX: gnome-
XDG_SESSION_CLASS: user
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP: ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_TYPE: x11
XMODIFIERS: @im=ibus
MANAGERPID: 2170
INVOCATION_ID: db98fc4b5a6a427f834b0c9714a7d95a
JOURNAL_STREAM: 8:20784
SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID: 2696
MEMORY_PRESSURE_WATCH: /sys/fs/cgroup/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/org.gnome.Shell@x11.service/memory.pressure
MEMORY_PRESSURE_WRITE: c29tZSAyMDAwMDAgMjAwMDAwMAA=
GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT: stderr
GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS: JS ERROR;JS LOG
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE: /usr/share/applications/pgadmin4.desktop
GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID: 57576
GDK_BACKEND: x11
NO_AT_BRIDGE: 1
PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 5050
PGADMIN_INT_KEY: 2cfaa882-5873-4fec-97e0-c78ea7d492c2
PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF


Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.006 Sec
Failed to launch pgAdmin4. Error:
Error: spawn /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin/python3 ENOENT
I deleted pgadmin and reinstalled it, but still the same error

Again I found the answer myself in this commad:
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python python3

